# Change operation of function to do nothing in MONO

Tags: mono

I have a Windows .NET assembly which I want to use, preferably unchanged, on Linux under Mono. Unfortunately there are function calls in the assembly that exist in my Windows DLLs but not in the equivalent Linux shared object libraries. Is it possible to somehow use the .dll.config file to make those function calls do nothing, something like the following...

```
<dllmap="Windows.dll>
    <dllentry dll="Linux.so" name="somefunction" target=""/>
</dllmap>
```

Assume I am unable to change the existing DLLs or shared objects.

Thanks